# VBA - Decrement a for loop within an if

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, for-loop

I'm running a macro to clean up empty lines from a workbook, and due to how the For loop runs, it'll miss consecutive empty lines because it, for example:

- Checks line 14
- Deletes line 14 because blank
- Line 15 shifts up to become the *new* line 14
- For loop moves on to Line 15, missing the new line 14

My (possibly flawed) solution was to add a step after deleting the row which decrements the for loop by one step, so that it'll catch consecutives.

I tried:

```
For i = 1 To 2000
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 6)) = True Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        i = i - 1
    End If
Next i
```

Which seemed to loop infinitely. I also tried i -= 1, --i, etc but those fail due to an expected expression. i = --i atleast runs but doesn't seem to work in so far as removing blank lines.

Any advice? Apologies in advance if missed something obvious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should really step backwards when deleting, so start at 2000 and work your way down to 1 to ensure no lines are skipped.

```
For i = 2000 To 1 step -1
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 6)) = True Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Yes! I think that is best practice

Comment: Yup, this is what I've ended up doing after discussing with a colleague, and it works perfectly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try running it in reverse, so starting at 2000 (using your example, or I think Worksheet.Rows.Count) and working back down to 1. That way you won't need to fiddle with your loop index when you delete a row.

So:

```
For i = 2000 to 1 step -1
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 6)) = True Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

The reason why your current code loops is that line 2000 is blank, so it deletes it and sets your loop count back to 1999, so it then tries line 2000 again which is blank and so on.

Comment: Aha, I was wondering what exactly was causing the loop, and that makes sense!

Comment: My logic for the cause is right, but the number might not be. Its really when it reaches the end of your content. So it will probably be at a much lower number.

Comment: Looking at my data post-fix, yeah, it probably ran into it at about the 1500s or so. Same effect and cause, just different location! Many thanks for the help.

Comment: If you found my answer useful then please up vote it.

Comment: I have, but unfortunately I'm still below 15 rep, so won't display until I get above 15!